# What is the convective acceleration?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid

I want to gain a better understanding of the convective acceleration that occurs for instance in Navier. Why, in a permanent flow, there can still be acceleration?
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by permanent flow? In turbukent fliw the fluid can move in many directions.

Comment: By permanent flow I mean the velocity components of said flow are not a function of t.

Answer (score 1):

In a permanent flow, the velocity do not change with t. That is, if we compare two pictures of the flow, they're the same. However, the velocity can change in space, for instance, the velocity near the bounding surface is smaller than the velocity far from the surface. The convection acceleration translates this "spatial" variation of the velocity.